# How can I use a class derived from QWidget in a Windows Form?

Tags: qt, com, qgis, activeqt

I've been trying to create a COM object(.dll) out of a QWidget class to use in a C# Windows Form. The class in question is from a open source gis library called Qgis.

I know ActiveQt exists but the documentation for it is not that comprehensive and seems to be somewhat outdated.

My end goal is to create a "User Control"-like object in Qt and import it to a Visual Studio envorinment.

Can you point me to a guide or something to help me out.

Comment: check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583929/how-to-display-desktop-in-windows-form-using-qt

Comment: @FranciscoRaga , thats a standalone Qt application. Sadly thats not what i am looking for. I want to host a QWidget object in a Windows form and interact with it from C# code.

Comment: IIRC you will have to init QApplication within your "Qt-based DLL" for Qt being active. Then you should be able to expose the windowId to the hostapplication.

Comment: @SebastianLange, i doubt that. Activeqt examples in qt source doesnt init qapplication at all when they intend to create a dll. They dont even have a main function.