# Recording desktop using Qt multimedia

Tags: c++, qt, multimedia

I'm trying to record microphones, cameras and monitors using Qt's multimedia module. But I couldn't find anything about screen recording in documentation. So it seemed I'd to do it by myself.

I've searched about that, found that answer:
[How to display desktop in windows form using Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583929/how-to-display-desktop-in-windows-form-using-qt)

Seems I've to use FFMPEG to merge these taken screenshots into mp4 file, also it doesn't seem an efficient way. I want to show real time recording output with `QVideoWidget`. I was going to use `QMediaCaptureSession`, `QMediaRecorder`. But they only work with camera. Is there any way to record desktop screen with Qt's multimedia module?

P.S: Please correct me, if my question is wrong